# Why is the response object being returned with multiple parameters when it doesnt appear to take any?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am new learning to create rest API's using Node, Express and MySQL. I have my function removeAll that takes no parameters, it passes the result object into an arrow function which then runs a sql function which then takes another function as a parameter (err, res). Inside of the nested arrow function if we do not have any errors and the affected rows does not equal 0 we get to the result which returns (null, res).  Now my confusion is as to why result contains (null, res) rather than just res. I am also confused as to how res is actually being assigned, I see that it is being passed into the arrow function but we dont explicitly set what res is.

```
  sql.query("DELETE FROM customers", (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(null, err);
      return;
    }
    if (res.affectedRows == 0) {
      // customer not found with the id
      result({ kind: "not_found" }, null);
      return;
    }
    console.log("deleted customer with id: ", id) {
        result(null, res);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`result` is a node-style callback, where the first parameter is the error (if any; if no error, first parameter is `null`), and the second parameter is the result (if no error is encountered).

The general approach is very similar to the `sql.query` callback you're using:

```
sql.query("DELETE FROM customers", (err, res) => {
```

Just like how *its* callback defines the error parameter first, and the result second, you similarly want to call `result` with the error as the first parameter, or else with the result as the second parameter.

That said, `result` is a pretty confusing variable name - it's a callback, not a result which contains data, so you might want to rename it to something more appropriate, so as to reduce potential confusion.

> I am also confused as to how res is actually being assigned

It's handled by the internals of `sql.query`. When the query resolves successfully, it will do something like `callback(null, results)`. When the query fails, it will do something like `callback(someError)`. `callback` is the callback that you pass to `sql.query`.

Answer (score 1):

> Now my confusion is as to why result contains (null, res) rather than just res.

That's the standard way old-style Node.js callbacks work: The first argument is an error or `null`, and if the first argument isn't an error, the second argument contains the data "returned" by the call.

These days, you'd use a promise, but that's how the old-style callbacks work.

> I am also confused as to how res is actually being assigned, I see that it is being passed into the arrow function but we dont explicitly set what res is.

The `sql.query` function is what calls the callback you pass into it. That's where `res` comes from, it's the result of the database operation. `sql.query` also follows the standard old-style Node.js callback pattern.